# low level caching with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching, instagram-graph-api

I want to make a request to a read only API (instagram) and cache the answer so I only do it once every hour.
My code is as follow

```
def update_images
    Rails.cache.fetch("instagram_api", expires_in: 1.hour) do 
        client = InstagramBasicDisplay::Client.new(auth_token: ENV["INSTAGRAM_TOKEN"])
        instagram_feed = []
    
        client.media_feed.body["data"].each do |feed|
            if feed["media_url"].include? "scontent"
                instagram_feed.push(feed["media_url"])
            end
        end
        instagram_feed 
    end
end
```

however every time I refresh the page I it makes a new request to the API. No idea whats wrong with my code, in theory it should work. But for some reason rails is not caching anything

btw, this logic is in my controller.

Comment: Protip. In Ruby 2.7+ you can just write `client.media_feed.body["data"].map_filter { |feed| feed["media_url"] if feed["media_url"].include?("scontent") }` instead of this clunky solution. In earlier versions use `each_with_object` instead.

Comment: As to the caching problem - have you actually ensured that caching is turned on in the environment you're in? Its off by default in development.